# Isn't $_POST array supposed to be in order of DOM?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a form that looks like this

```
<table class="audio_channels">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="channel">
            <td>
                <label>Field1</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field1]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field2</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field2]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field3</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field3]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field4</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field4]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="channel">
            <td>
                <label>Field1</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field1]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field2</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field2]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field3</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field3]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Field4</label><br>
                <select name="value[][field4]">
                    <option value="option">option</option>
                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using `[]` to auto increment dynamically added fields, and it was working great on one form, but in another, the var_dump of `$_POST['value']` looks like:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field1"]=>
    string(6) "option"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field1"]=>
    string(6) "option"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field2"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field2"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field3"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field3"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field4"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["field4"]=>
    string(6) "option"  }
}
```

Notice field1, field1 and then field2, field2.. rather than going by row (which is happening elsewhere in the document.)

Why is this happening? All that I've read states that things should be put into the $_POST variable in the order they appear in the DOM, and this would appear to not be doing that.

I'm probably going to have to hardcode an incrementing key to be sure, but I'm curious about why it would be coming out this way when everything I've read implies it should be in DOM order

Comment: Chrome wraps the `<tr>` tags in `<tbody>` because that's well-formed HTML. You should be doing this yourself (except that you only need one `<tbody>` wrapping around your `<tr>` tags). If there's a header row, wrap it in a `<thead>` tag (the row should have `<th>` tags instead of `<td>` tags). If there's a footer row, wrap it in a `<tfoot>` tag (this can have `<td>` tags in the row. Both `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` belong above `<tbody>`.

Comment: I'm ajaxing `<tr>`s in and even with a `<tbody>` tag already there Chrome wraps each `<tr>` in a `<tbody>`

Comment: Could be a bug. I wouldn't worry about it - it's still valid.

Comment: I wasn't too worried about it just thought it was strange. I'm primarly concerned with why the $_POST array is not in DOM order

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
value[][fieldX]
```

to

```
value[fieldX]
```

And maybe you need to group the values with:

```
value[groupX][fieldX]
```

E.g.

```
value[row1][field1]
value[row1][field2]
value[row1][field3]

value[row2][field1]
value[row2][field2]
value[row2][field3]
```

Comment: yeah the reason I had [] was so that I didn't have to worry about incrementing a row number. Then I was chunking the array into 4. Just find it massively strange that it is in the wrong order within the $_POST variable